# include a JSP page in a Facelets page

Tags: jsp, jsf, include, facelets

How can I include a JSP page in a Facelets page?

`mypage.xhtml`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>


    </h:body>
</html>
```

`header.jsp`

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="index.xhtml">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="login.xhtml">Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facelets has no builtin support for including JSP files. JSP is a deprecated view technology and Facelets is basically its successor. As JSP is deprecated, you shouldn't expect that there are any plans for its support.

Just rename `header.jsp` to `header.xhtml` and eliminate any JSP specific artifacts. There's nothing in JSP which would be "impossible" with JSF/Facelets.

As a temporary resort, you could use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`<o:resourceInclude>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/resourceInclude) tag to embed the output of a JSP/Servlet page in Facelets. Note that it's thus like how `<c:import>` works and that it would only work with static content.

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959)

Answer (score 1):

Use OmniFaces  http://omnifaces.org

You can use it in this way

```
<o:resourceInclude path="/someJSPpage.jsp" />
```

reference:

http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/resourceInclude